# Indexing only individual values in property arrays (instead of indexing every combination of those values) in Google datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

The data model I am planning would have a few property "fields" in place, including a "category/tags" property, which would be a list/array of a lot of tags.

I'm planning on querying on one category at a time.  I am not interested in indexing which entities have combinations of categories, just individual categories.

I am NOT referencing simply not indexing a particular property.

**Bonus Question:**

It seems Google datastore doesn't like "monotonically increasing" property values (ie timestamps) because presumably they make hotspots on the machines while forming indexes.  **So would just storing the current calendar date help?**  I could see that making even more of a "hotspot" since every entity for 24 hours would have the same index value for that property, is there some way of storing some data about when each entity was recorded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, one should encounter no issues creating a builtin index, as mentioned in the above reply. Still, properties with array values can behave in [surprising ways](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries#datastore-basic-query-java). For more than one filter, all conditions defined by the filters must be satisfied by at least one of the array’s individual values, for it to match the query. This does not apply in case of the equality filters.

Sort order is also unusual: the first value seen in the index determines an entity's sort order.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a property index (aka Built-in Index) on an Array property creates the index with various value combinations. I believe each value in the Array is indexed. For example, if you have a Book with two tags, the index will have two entries for each tag. Adding another book with three tags would add 3 more entries to the Tags index. This index allows you to query for books based on a single tag as well as multiple tags.

The "combination of values" that you mentioned happens if you create a composite index containing more than one Array type (e.g. Authors and Tags of a Book), and all/most books have multiple authors and multiple tags.

You should not have any issues creating a builtin index on your Category/Tag.

On your other question on indexing entity created/modified timestamp, I do see that the [Best Practices](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#indexes) says to avoid indexing such a property.

> Do not index properties with monotonically increasing values (such as
>   a NOW() timestamp). Maintaining such an index could lead to hotspots
>   that impact Cloud Datastore latency for applications with high read
>   and write rates

Not sure what the alternative would be. If you don't have to query on the timestamp/sort on the timestamp, you are fine storing the timestamp by excluding the property from indexing.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be the way indexing works with Google datastore since I have created some simple entities and the number of indexes reported for those entities are more than what you have described.                                    .                                                                                                                               Unless I have misunderstood something.

Comment: Also the query "tag1" AND "tag2" is valid, yet the query "tag1" OR "tag2" is not valid.  Which seems to lend credence to the idea that combination indexes are automatically indexed.  Furthermore that's the only method I know which would scale completely independently of database size, and instead scale with results size.

Comment: When you say "number of indexes" - what exactly are you referring to? OR queries are not yet natively supported by the Cloud Datastore.

Comment: "number of indexes" = 'built-in index count' as reported in the "datastore dashboard".